# Limit of $x^{{\frac{1}{x}}^{\frac{1}{x}}}-x$ as $x$ goes to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

From what I tried to do I got, but I don’t know what it means:

$a=x^{{\frac{1}{x}}^{\frac{1}{x}}}$ 
$a’=(x^{{\frac{1}{x}}^{\frac{1}{x}} -\frac{1}{x}-2)}\cdot (\ln^2(x)-\ln(x)+x)$

$a-x$ 
multiply by $\frac{x}{x}$ 
$$(a-x)\cdot(\frac{x}{x})=\frac{ax-x^2}{x}$$ 
Derive using l’hospitals rule 
$a+a’x-2x$

Comment: Might mean it goes to 0? Only a guess.

Comment: Are you analyzing $(x^{(1/x)})^{(1/x)}$ or $x^{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}}$? I think it is the second form.

Comment: @Axion004 you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to +\infty}{\left(x^{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}}-x\right)}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}{x\left(x^{x^{-\frac{1}{x}}-1}-1\right)}&=\lim_{x\to +\infty}{x\left(\mathrm{e}^{\ln{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}-1\right)}-1\right)}\\&=x\ln{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}-1\right)\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\ln{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}-1\right)}-1}{\ln{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}-1\right)}\right)\\ &=-\ln^{2}{x}\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}-1}{-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}\right)\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\ln{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}-1\right)}-1}{\ln{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}-1\right)}\right)\\&=-\infty\times 1\times 1\\ &=-\infty\end{aligned}

Because $ \lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{\ln{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}-1\right)}=\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}{-4\left(\frac{\ln{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}-1}{-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}\right)}=-4\times 0\times 1=0 $, leading to : $$ \lim_{x\to +\infty}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\ln{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}-1\right)}-1}{\ln{x}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\ln{x}}{x}}-1\right)}}=1 $$

Comment: The exponential also works but requires a lot more algebraic manipulations than taking the logarithm!

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x\to\frac1x$ so that the limit is at $0$, and then use that [$e^x-1\sim x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#Equivalent_infinitesimal)  to simplify the exponentiation.

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^{\frac1x^\frac1x}-x)
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\left(\frac1x\right)^{x^x}-\frac1x\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1x\left(\left(\frac1x\right)^{x^x-1}-1\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1x\left(e^{(\ln \frac1x)(x^x-1)}-1\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1x(\ln \frac1x)(x^x-1)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1x(\ln \frac1x)(e^{x\ln x}-1)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1x(\ln \frac1x)(x\ln x)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}(-\ln^2 x)\\
&=-\infty.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: This approach works (+1) and is easier than dealing with the exponential.